# VS 2010 Extension Access Loaded Types

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vs-extensibility

I am currently try to write a code generator and I would like the user to select the target type for a property on a class via a drop down, but to populate the drop down I need to know what types are available to the project.

How do I access via a VS extension the properties that have been loaded by the current project?

Answer (score 0):

Check out my answer here:
[How to access project code meta data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523918/how-to-access-project-code-meta-data/10642840#10642840)

You should be able to get the types from the code snippet I provided.