# Framework or tools to analyze .NET code

Tags: c#, .net, code-analysis, ndepend

I'm looking for any software which can:
- analyze .NET source code (c# or vb.net)
- build some repository which can be queried (NDepend and Resharper do something similar)
- allow to query this repository looking for classes, methods, calling methods, and so on (like Resharper or NDpend)
- accessing to the method's name, local variables name, type, static value and also method text

I would like to use it for creating the documentation about the stored procedure called by this software.

***NDepend*** is a really wonderful tool that analyzes the IL / source code and allows you to write queries like the following one, **but** doesn't provide access to the constant value of the string (I need them to identify the stored procedure name / parameters).

```
from m in Types.WithFullNameNotIn( "Core.DbObject").ChildMethods() 
let depth0 = m.DepthOfIsUsing("Core.DbObject")
where depth0  >= 0 
&& !m.Name.Contains(".ctor")
orderby depth0
select new { m, depth0 }
```

**What is my final purpose?**

I've got a big source code in Vb.net. I would like to track every call to the stored procedure saving:

The call to the stored procedure behave as it follows:

```
RunProcedure("dbo.Log", parameters, "Log_LoadFromID")
```

I need to extract:

- the name of the Vb.NET **Method** --> easy using IL and metadata information
- the name of the **Stored Procedure** --> easy using textual analisys of code
- the list of the **parameters passed** to the store --> easy using textual analisys of code

I've tried to look for it but I couldn't find anything similar to this.

**EDIT**

I've found something here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10642840/196210

**Extra details:**

*I think it's really hard to find a similar software.
So I've no problem if it's a plugin for Visual Studio as well as a standalone tool or a .NET framework. Also it doesn't matter were this info will be exported. It's only important that I can use this info. I need to generate a report. For sure, I guess, it will be a Windows Software or a .NET Framework, but if you find an Android App doing this it will be ok as well :-)*

Comment: This probably belongs on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I'm question banned there.. I would really appreciate if you would open the question there for me..

Comment: If this question is indeed on-topic for the recs site, I'll happily ask for you. However, I'm not going to end up question banned on your behalf.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar: yes, don't worry.. I've been banned for my behaviour on meta.SR. But since now I'm banned on whole website, I thank you if you will open this question over there..

Comment: Pending responses to this meta.sr question: http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/747/1317

Comment: @mikeTheLiar: thanks for your effort. I've seen the question would be OT also on the other site. I don't understand why, but it's not a problem :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49154/discussion-between-miketheliar-and-revious)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49161/discussion-between-miketheliar-and-revious)

Answer (score 1):

For your requirements, I guess you're looking for a software like http://www.nitriq.com/

Comment: Can you also access info like the name of the local variable? Or the value of the constant string that are the names of the stored procedure?